# How can I control+click files/folders with a touch screen and on screen keyboard in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

Using a keyboard and mouse you can intermittently select files by pressing control and clicking the files you want to select. When using the touch screen the control button no longer functions in the same manner. Is there any way to simulate or recreate the regular control click behavior using only the touch screen and the on screen keyboard?

Comment: In addition to James' answer, you can also enable the checkboxes permanently: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10723-check-boxes-select-items-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Comment: I believe you can double tab the ctrl key on the on-screen keyboard to make it stick, and double tab the ctrl key to unstick it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this maybe?

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-select-multiple-files-on-windows-8-tablet/

Comment: Provide the relevant info in the post.  Link-only answers are discouraged.